# CSS Multi-level drop down not working

Tags: html, css, menu

Ok - I give up! I don't have much experience with CSS but I'm trying to create a simple CSS multi-level drop down. I almost have it working but cannot figure out one thing... when I hover over a top level menu ALL sub level menus (2nd & 3rd) display for that item. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?? I've tried many solutions - and this is where I'm at. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
#ddmenu {
font-size: .9em; 
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 15px;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 2px;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.2);
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #8aa8bd;
z-index: 5000;
}

#ddmenu ul {
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;
top: 25px;
width: 180px;
background: #fff;
display: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 0;
list-style: none;
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#ddmenu li {
font-size: 0.9em; 
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
z-index: 5000;
line-height: 30px;
color: #6c87c0;
padding: 0 10px;
white-space: none;
}

#ddmenu li a {
display: block;
float: left;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

#ddmenu li:hover > a {
color: #7180a0;
background: #d9e2ee;
}

/* level 3+ list */
#ddmenu ul ul {
left: 180px;
top: -3px;
}
```

HTML is:

```
<ul id="ddmenu">
    <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">New</A></LI>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Show All</A></LI>
      </ul>
    </LI>
    <LI><a href="javascript: void(0);">Layers</a>
        <ul>

            <li><A HREF="javascript: void(0);">Trans 1</A>
            <UL>            
                <li><A HREF="javascript: void(0);">sub one</A></LI>             
                <li><A HREF="javascript: void(0);">sub two</A></LI>             
                <li><A HREF="javascript: void(0);">sub three</A></LI>               
            </UL>
            </li>

            <li><A HREF="javascript: void(0);">Trans 2</A>
            <UL>            
                <li><A HREF="javascript: void(0);">sub one</A></LI>         
            </UL>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </LI>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey change the href for your second level menu's ... better yet use classes for eahc menu level and then javascript listeners instead of the current href

Comment: Some code is missing. Your current CSS will not display any submenus on hover because there is nothing changing child `ul` elements to `display: block` rather than `display: none`. You are either missing some CSS rules or Javascript that is involved in this menu.  But I suspect your problem can be solved by using the `>` child selector (assuming this is in fact a pure CSS menu).  Replicate your code and bug in a JSfiddle and it will be much easier to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking at a pure CSS menu (no quite sure what you are trying to do with all the `javascript: void(0);` but if your just testing the setup `#` is less to type), it appears you are missing how to display something. i.e. nowhere do I see a `:hover { display: block;}` (or something other than none). To make things simpler for myself, I tend to do the CSS to get the menu working first, then make it look nicer (including the transitions). So I have striped the code right back to just the CSS required to display the menu correctly, I will leave making it look nicer up to you, but this is roughly what I usually do:

```
#ddmenu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;            
}

#ddmenu > li {
    display: inline;
}

#ddmenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

#ddmenu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#ddmenu ul li ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;            
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<ul id="ddmenu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Show All</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="layerhomelink">Layers</a>
        <ul>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Trans 1
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">sub one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Trans 2
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">sub one</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The widths may also need to be adjusted, based on what you want.This should be fine in most browser including back to IE 8

so next step, putting back the styling (the making it look nicer bits) which I separated into the following:

```
 #ddmenu a {
        padding: .5em;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        transition: all 0.2s linear;
    }

    #ddmenu {
        font-size: .9em;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 15px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.2);
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #8aa8bd;
    }

        #ddmenu ul {
            width: 180px;
            background: #fff;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 7px 0;
            border-radius: 3px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        #ddmenu li {
            font-size: 0.9em;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
            line-height: 30px;
            color: #6c87c0;
            padding: 0 10px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

            #ddmenu li li a {
                display: block;               
            }

            #ddmenu li:hover > a {
                color: #7180a0;
                background: #d9e2ee;
            }
```

all should be good. Ultimately I usually combine the css, but sometimes it is cleaner to keep them separate (FORM from FUNCTION), even in different CSS files, so that you could re-theme the menu, without breaking its functionality.

I find trying to do a CSS menu with floats AND positioning to be doubling up, and confusing. This is purely using positioning, with the parent element being position relative, which in essence does nothing apart from letting you position its child elements absolutely within it. I use widths in percentages as this then positions the child menus correctly regardless of different widths, and font / pixel sizes so you don't get in a granular war over pixels. Please note though, putting margins or padding in the wrong place may change the menu, so adjustment as you go may be required. I would go in small steps (like one style rule at a time), and test what you have changed, in all browsers you can, just to make sure that you don't inadvertently change the menus behaviour.

Anyway hope that helps

Comment: No problems, added some more to my answer if you are interested

Comment: Now @Angela I notice that you have asked 4 question here on SO, but not accepted any of the answers (assuming there is answers of course). Please if an answers has helped you to solve you question, etiquette and courtesy here on SO means you should give it a tick, to help the community (it will be displayed int the top left corner under the number with arrow above and below it of the answer). Initially the tick will be just an outline, but once you have accepted an answer, it will go green next to that answer (i.e. click the tick). It will give you some more rep points too.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for the first dropdown level would be:

Just add a

```
#ddmenu li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

But I suggest you build it from scratch, first the HTML structure, then the CSS, without any effects (border, etc).